# Reference alternate to reference assembly in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use an alternative core framework library while still targeting .NET Framework 4.0. When I add a manual reference to the alternate file, Visual Studio instead creates a reference to the same named file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\`.

Can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the dll is already in the GAC, removing existing dlls will not work.
Try to mark the reference as `Specific Version = true` (Right click -> Properties).

EDIT:
After you have added the reference (even if the wrong one was actually added), edit your csproj file, find the reference, and edit it with your specific dll properties:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>True</SpecificVersion>  
  <HintPath>..\..\ExternalLibrary\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: I can't mark `Specific Version = true` without first being able to add the reference.

Comment: Doing this, plus finding the new strong name of the replacement assembly, worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. You also want to do `<Private>True</Private>` so it does `Copy Local`; otherwise on deployment you will have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
1 - Remove the reference.

2 - Clear your project bin/debug folder. If possible delete these
folders!

3 - Add the reference again.
```

You may need to restart Visual Studio between the steps described above.

Comment: Try to run the Clean solution command in Visual Studio... Are you sure you can use this alternative DLL with .NET 4.0? Does it support .NET 4? Take a look at this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575253/old-dll-keeps-being-used

Comment: Tried Clean as well. The DLL definitely supports .NET 4.0.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remove core DLLs from the GAC, so that solution won't work.