# Azure references incorrect DLL

Tags: c#, azure, dll

This is somewhat of a follow up to: [Reference alternate to reference assembly in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019415/reference-alternate-to-reference-assembly-in-visual-studio-2010)

I am referencing an alternative version of a core framework DLL. Visual Studio (and the local debugger fabric) has no problem referencing this file. Additionally, the file is marked `Copy Local`. However, when I deploy to the cloud, I get:

> Could not load file or assembly '(assembly strong name)' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

Using remote desktop, I determined that the correct file is indeed in the `E:\approot` folder along with my other dependencies. I am assuming that the fabric is looking in the GAC instead of using my files.

Is there a way to force it to use my DLL first?

**Note:** The entire concept of replacing a .NET CLR DLL is a huge hack anyway, so hacks are welcome. When .NET 4.5 comes out supporting the feature I need, this will all be stripped out.

Further info: It appears my web role works fine, but my worker role dies with that error when it attempts to build my Autofac container. This happens even if I explicitly load the assembly before building it, which also works fine.

Comment: Hmm, what you are doing is specifically forbidden in the license.  The odds that Azure enforces this, or assumes it, are non-zero.  The ngen-ed version of the DLL might play a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a fusion log to see where it is loading from.  You may need to create a .config file for the process if something else is running and loading that file first.  You may be able to do something exotic also like create a new appdomain and load your assembly there, something like what this does for dynamic assemblies:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2007/12/05/dynamic-assemblies-and-what-to-do-about-them.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the Appdomain.AssemblyResolve event to catch it and load it manually. However, i don't know if it's fired and it is a workaround.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I'll give it a shot. The whole concept is a workaround anyway until .NET 4.5 comes out, which should include what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try hinting the CLR that shall probe first in the local folder:

```
<runtime> 
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"> 
  <probing privatePath="." /> 
</assemblyBinding> 
</runtime>
```

Check out more on Locating Assembly by Probing section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3.aspx). This might help.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this issue befure if one of the project's doesn't have the .NET Framework version targetted. Perhaps check to make sure all projects in the solution have the same setting.

Comment: This isn't related to framework version. I am replacing a CLR DLL, which means every framework version is the wrong framework version. I need to force it to load the correct dll.

Comment: kk. Sorry. I've just seen that same error when there are different .net framework versions in the solution.