# Visual Studio deployment package build includes old files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build

This thing is driving me crazy, I dont know what is going on.

I create a deployment package for my ASP.NET MVC 3 application, and MY MAIN DLL FILE inside the package is dated 1/31/2013, and today is 2/3/2013. I have made tons of changes during those couple of days.

It packs old files!!! Where on earth did it get january version??? Because i cant find it anywhere else. Why does it hold a reference to it at all?

During the same period I created few views, dated 2/2/2013 and those are included...

PackageTemp (/obj/Release) folder contains old dlls, while my /bin folder contains fresh ones?

Any idea, what could cause this?

Comment: Did you delete obj and bin and package folder and then right click on solution and clean solution and right click on solution and click rebuild solution. it maby works

Comment: I did all that, maybe not in that order, but i did. I'll try in your order, but i have a hunch, that it wont work...

Comment: Nothing, still saying freaking 1/31/2013 8:40 PM. These kind of things really annoy me

Answer (score 0):

[here's your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575253/old-dll-file-keeps-being-used)
It hides it in the GAC. There it may reside indefinitely. Using a more recent version may indeed solve the problem, but there is an outstanding bug in Visual Studio that has to do with choosing the correct version of DLL files. (If DLL Hell wasn't bad enough, the Visual Studio team is making it worse!)

Finding it in the GAC is tricky, and I cannot advise you on how to do that, but once the old version is deleted from there, it will not be found again. Sometimes, even though you are pointing the compiler at a newer version (by date), it will use the older version, because it has the same version level (by version). That is its bug.

Comment: great, that's a good pointer. I'll just increase version number, that should solve the problem...

Comment: dear @MilosMijatovic, I think search on google is a necessary  skill for programmers, i get the answer only with one search :)