# Why still looks for the code in another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I moved those methods to a totally different assembly. Before they where simple static methods and I re-wrote them as extensions.
But the compiler still looks for the old assembly.
I removed the assembly reference from web.config and put the new one. Also I fully searched for the old assembly name in the solution and there's no sighn of it.
I even fully referenced the call (as you can see below) but this thing still asks for the old one.
Is there anything I missed?

```
No se puede cargar el tipo 'ENF.Controls.HtmlExtensions' del ensamblado'ENF.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. 
  Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código. 

 Detalles de la excepción: System.TypeLoadException: No se puede cargar el tipo 'ENF.Controls.HtmlExtensions' del ensamblado'ENF.Controls, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Error de código fuente:

Línea 72:         </asp:UpdatePanel>
Línea 73:     </form>
Línea 74:     <%=ENF.Tools.Web.MasterPageExtensions.JSFromCdnWithFallback(Me, "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js", "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js", "$.fn.modal")%>
Línea 75:     <%=ENF.Tools.Web.MasterPageExtensions.JSFromCdnWithFallback(Me, "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js", "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js", "$.ui")%>
Línea 76:   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="script_container" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Have you tried a clean then build?

Comment: Try to rebuid solution.

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575253/old-dll-file-keeps-being-used (it may be cached in the GAC)

Comment: Yes, I've tried clean and rebuild several times. I don't know if it can be cached in GAC. Those are my own libraries and I never configured to be in the GAC. I'm looking at it.

Comment: Have you checked in the .csproj file for any lingering references?