# Visual Studio Won't Update Path to New DLL

Tags: visual-studio

Running VS 2015. Have a new version of a dll. Have a VB.net solution that uses a DLL provided by a manufacturer. That DLL has been updated. No matter what I do, I can't force VS to see the new reference to the DLL at a new path. Keeps failing the build, saying it can't find the old dll at the old path.

Found this thread:
[Old DLL file keeps being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575253/old-dll-file-keeps-being-used)

As suggested in that thread, I've tried searching for it in the GAC (not found), updating the version of the new DLL, deleting all references, etc. Tried using the Modules window, but that only works when running or in break mode, and I can't get there. Tried upgrading to VS19, same result.

The ONLY thing that seems to work is to start a new solution, add all my source files, and then point to the new DLL location. But that's not a tenable solution when this happens regularly.

Any more thoughts?

Comment: Please post some of your code so we can help yoiu debug. What does your .CONFIG file look like? Please also let us know what kind of project this is.

Comment: Have you tried including both in the project, renaming the old version to basically make it useless and then rebuilding? Just a random thought.

Comment: @haag1 - I can't even find the old version. It doesn't exist at the path VS is looking for it at.

Comment: You could always track down that version online and add it back into your solution/project. Get it to build, and move from there. Not a great solution, but a starting point, at least get it building again.

Comment: @codeMonkey: not sure what code you'd like to see. Don't think this is a code issue. The error message I get is: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error BC2017 could not find library '..\..\..\..\..\..\FW_Qualification_Suite\beagle-api-windows-x86_64-v5.10\beagle-api-windows-x86_64-v5.10\net\beagle_net.dll' PR Firmware Qualification C:\Users\A4BKJZZ\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\PR Firmware Qualification\vbc 1 Active

Comment: @haag1 - can't even add back the old version. It's stuck looking in the one location I posted above.

Comment: If this is a VB project, you should have a .VBPROJ file that contains the reference.

Comment: @codeMonkey: you are correct, it does contain the reference. So I edited it to my new location/version...and it still is pointing to the old location/version when I build. '    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="beagle_net">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\beagle_net.dll</HintPath>'

Comment: All: I hadn't noticed it at first, but my .VBPROJ file actually contained TWO mentions of that DLL. The first was the one I posted above, the "Reference include" path. I changed that, and it had no effect. However, at the end of the VBPROJ file was a second mention in an ItemGroup called "Analyzer". I manually updated this path, and now my project will build. However, I have no idea why a library file for a USB protocol analyzer would end up here. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your .VBPROJ file.  There is a good chance you have more than one reference to the same dependency and can either get rid of one, or ensure that all have the same path.

Comment: Did you not bother reading the comments on this post? It was talked about almost 24 hours ago and just 4 hours ago OP even acknowledged this...

Comment: @haag1 I am the person from the comments who told him to check his VBROJ file, and that was the correct answer to help him build. I read the comments on this post -- because I wrote them. :)