# nopCommerce Caching nop.web Issue

Tags: iis, caching, nopcommerce

I have my websites running on nopCommerce. The Site is hosted on a private server on IIS.

Here we have only used nopCommerce core files for caching and have not used any other mechanism.

The problem I am facing is, Randomly nopweb.dll is replaced with an older version of the file and it causes site down.
The Issue gets resolved by just replacing the Nop.Web.dll from the backup folder or new dll of that.

I have read many articles but have not found any solution for that yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a same issue for nopCommerce3.4 where the new Nop.Web.dll replaced by the old Nop.Web.dll after a certain time of period. I got a solution  by following [Clear GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575253/old-dll-file-keeps-being-used)

Comment: I have deleted all the related files from the assembly but no luck

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Then wherefrom the .dll coming? Hope for the best. Please share if you get solution. But we delete the temp file to GAC. That was done by the server guy by the way.

Comment: Yes. I am also wonder how it comes ? I have deleted all reference of the nop.web.dll found in search other than wwwroot.I have cleared manually using shift+DEL. I may need to consult server expert or have some knowledge of that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enable stdout log from web.config file and then check logs from application root folder > Logs.

Open the latest log file(or when your site is down) and find an error log with fail group. 
this log will show you the exact error message.

[image]

Comment: It is not taking new property value, when we take over project it was 90% complete. And we have added property in existing class. The thing is those properties are not reflected when this error comes.; if we delete the nop.web and replace again with the same code then it starts working

Comment: Site is not getting down. The Page which has modification gives internal server error. (Reason : it is not able to find the new property value , may be cache issue)