# Any reason editing an ActionScript 3 file in Flash wouldn't actually edit it?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For the life of me, no matter how I edit this ActionScript 3 file (Main.as) it doesn't actually change anything. It's linked to my Flash document as "Main" class. Everything works just fine, but I have to change one line of code, but it always runs at the original code I saved it at, even if I changed something and save it.

Is there any reason this could be possible? I've even tried just deleting the Main.as file and everything still works, so it seems as if it's embedded in Flash, but I can't find it!

If anybody knows if/why this would happen, any help would be great, because this is a true head banger for me. Thanks!

Aaron

Comment: Jenine comes to mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193953/flash-cs4-refuses-to-let-go

Comment: Ha, what an excellent post. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like Jenine was solved... although this describes by problem perfectly.

Comment: Did you try the first answer, which was accepted? Try deleting that file.

Comment: Yes, there were no ASO files to delete, I also tried doing the "Delete All ASO Files" within Flash itself... no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this before.

Just make sure if that if you have the class referenced as Main.as, Main.as is sat right next to your .fla file.

Or, if Main.as is within a sub directory such as com, make sure the base class is referenced as com.Main within your .fla's property panel.

If that still doesn't work I would change the class name in the .fla properties panel to Main2, click the pencil button to create a new .as file, then immediately save the file right next to your .fla file. This should create the linkage correctly and you can then copy/paste your original AS3 into your new Main2.as file.

Answer (score 2):

You probably edit the wrong AS3 file. Check the classpath of the flash movie. I don't have a Flash handy, but this guy tells you how to [set/change the classpath](http://moonpixel.com/flash-add-path-to-your-classes-as3-classpath/).

Comment: Thanks, I checked and tried adding a custom path, but it didn't seem to change anything.. seems like such a simple problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it still applies to AS3 compilation but you could try clearing your ASO file:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000187.html

Comment: Thanks, I really thought this would work, but looks like AS2 only... definitely on the right track though.

Answer (score 0):

It is matter how you editing your `Main.as`. If you open file for editing by clicking on the button with a pencil near the `Class` textfield, you will open a really linked file. If you edit your `Main.as` by a third-party editor, it is possible that you edit a wrong file. Look at paths in the "ActionScript Settings...". Maybe you have another `Main.as`.

Comment: Yeah, I've checked about 100 times just to be sure, but no dice. It seems like it's cached somewhere. I've even tried clearing my browser's cache, different computers, etc..